# Configure Wildcard url request in sitecore mvc 6.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, wildcard

I am trying to implement the sitecore wildcard url routing in the sitecore 6.6 which is MVC based.
I am missing something due to which the url is not well formed.
Could you please help me achieve this if you have any idea.

http://d.local.mvcsitecore.com/Store/Browse/,-w-,Genre.aspx?Genre=Classical

This is the url that is formed.

Comment: Are you having issues resolving/handling the item or in generating the correct custom URLs using the LinkManager?

Comment: Can you post the code? And specify what you want to achieve in a more detailed way?

Comment: I am trying to handle routing but the the url formation is going wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is related to routing but some custom LinkProvider instead. Check your code for an overridden instance of GetItemUrl method in Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider. You may need to post your code here for us to be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Is the target item selected for wildcard route you've created? You will also need to replace the tokens yourself, it won't happen automatically as far as I know.

```
var ts = WildcardManager.Provider.GetWildcardUrl(item, Sitecore.Context.Site);
var data = new NameValueCollection { { "%Token%", value } };
var url = ts.ReplaceTokens(data);
```